# How can I update/replace char at any position in the custom input field react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a custom currency input field using reactjs .Here I am trying to update the value onKeyDown based on keypress I am able to remove the input value at any position but my input cursor is automatically moving at end of value and when I move the cursor and trying to enter value in between the existing value it is appending to end the existing value but I want to update the value at removed index postion.

1. enter amount say 12.23
2. Now move the cursor to first digit and remove the 1 and enter 2.
3. Observe that user is not able to make amount as 22.23
4. Try to edit the value at any place.
5. Observe that user fails to edit the digits at particular places.
   Expected Results:
   User should be able to edit the particular digits of Payment amount.
   Actual Results:
   User is not able to edit the particular digits of Payment amount.
   my parent component

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { CurrencyInput } from './customInput';

function App() {
  let defaultAmount = '' 

  const [paymentAmount, setPaymentAmount] = useState(defaultAmount);
  const [paymentAmountValid, setPaymentValid] = useState(true);



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CurrencyInput controlId="paymentAmount"
        label={""}
        value={paymentAmount}
        max={3000.00}
        min={1.00}
        message={'payment-invalid-message-residential'}
        setValidity={setPaymentValid}
        setValue={setPaymentAmount}
        defaultValue="0">
      </CurrencyInput>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my custom input component

```
import React, { useCallback, useRef } from "react";
// import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { useState } from "react";
import _ from "lodash";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";




export const CurrencyInput = ({ value, setValue, controlId, label, max, min, required, message, setValidity,defaultValue }) => {
    // const { t } = useTranslation();
    const [isValid, setValid] = useState(true);
    const amountInvalidMessage = "amount-invalid";
    const amountRequiredMessage = "amount-required";
    const [invalidMessage, setInvalidMessage] = useState(amountInvalidMessage);    
    const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", { style: "currency", currency: "USD", currencyDisplay: "narrowSymbol"})
    const currencyInput= useRef(null)
    const validate = useCallback(_.debounce((amount) => {
        let valid = true;
        
        if (amount !== null && amount !== "") {
            amount= amount.replace("$","")
            let amountNumber = parseFloat(amount);
            if (isNaN(amountNumber)) {
                valid = false;
            } else if (min > amountNumber) {
                valid = false;
            } else if (max < amountNumber) {
                valid = false;
            }

            if(!valid) {
                setValue("");
                currencyInput.current.focus()                
                setInvalidMessage(amountInvalidMessage);
            }
        } else if (required) {
            valid = false;
            setValue("");
            currencyInput.current.focus()
            setInvalidMessage(amountRequiredMessage);
        }
        setValid(valid);
        setValidity(valid);
    }, 500), [min, max]);
    

    const onBlur = (e) => {
        if(value !== null && value !== "") {
            let formattedValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)
            setValue(formattedValue);
        }
        
        validate(value);
    }
    function removeAtIndex(str, index) {
        return str.substring(0, index - 1) + str.substring(index);
      }
    
    
    const onKeyDown = (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { selectionStart: i } = e.target;
        const index = e.keyCode === 8 ? i : i + 1;
        let formattedValue = removeAtIndex(value, index)
        if (parseFloat(formattedValue) === 0) {
          formattedValue = "";
        }
        setValue(formattedValue);
        return;
      }
      let currentInput = "";
      if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) currentInput = e.keyCode - 48;
      else if (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)
        //if it is non alpha numeric
        currentInput = e.keyCode - 96;
      else return;
      console.log("currentInput",currentInput)
      let formattedValue = value * 10 + parseInt(currentInput) / 100;
      console.log("formattedValue",formattedValue)
      formattedValue = formattedValue.toFixed(2).toString();
      if (formattedValue === "0.00") {
        formattedValue = "";
      }
      setValue(formattedValue);
    };
    return <Form.Group {...{ controlId }}>
        <Form.Control 
            type="text"
            isInvalid={!isValid}                       
            onBlur={onBlur}
            ref ={currencyInput}
            onKeyDown={onKeyDown}                    
            placeholder= {formatter.format(defaultValue)}  
            value={value}
            pattern="/\D/g">
        </Form.Control>
        {!isValid ? <Form.Control.Feedback className={'classes.feedbackInvalid'} type="invalid">{invalidMessage}</Form.Control.Feedback> : null}
    </Form.Group>
}
```

Comment: The issue should be fairly simple to illustrate.  Can you show us with less code?  A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). would be best.

Answer (score 0):

For me [react-number-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format) works as you expected, this lib has all required logic to work with number input

Comment: Is there anyway I can achieve without any 3rd party packages